# Spring REST + js FormData()

Tags: spring, rest, jetty

Пытаюсь подружиться со SPRING, подключил JETTY и commons-fileupload но не могу понять как вытащить HttpServletRequest ...
Отправляю Multipart из  JS:

```
save(e) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('demo0', 'hello1');
    formData.append('demo1', 'hello2');

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'demo', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

А как теперь прочитать содержимое?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/demo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void demo(???) { boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(---> HttpServletRequest request <---); }
```

---

Я понял, что бы вытащить содержимое 'demo1' и 'demo0' достаточно создать метод:

public void demo(@RequestParam("demo0") String demo0, @RequestParam("demo1") String demo1) { }

Но я бы хотел обойтись одним аргументом с каким-нибудь массивом и не обязательно загонять данные в "commons-fileupload", может можно обойтись средствами SPRINGa и перебрать эти пары ключ-значение?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все разобрался! Спасибо всем!

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/demo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void index(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            System.out.println(part.getName() + " ::: " + IOUtils.toString(request.getPart(part.getName()).getInputStream()));
        }
    }catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```